# Disable map panning using the arrow keys in the keyboard

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I have a Leaflet map that has `map.dragging.disable();` which works for mouse dragging. But when the map container is focused using the Tab key, pressing the arrow keys on the keyboard will still pan the map.

What I want is to completely disable map panning whether using the mouse, touchscreen, or keyboard, so that the map appears like a static image. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you are looking for the map option [keyboard](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-keyboard).

For simulating a static map with leaflet these options can do the trick:

```
var map = L.map('mapid'{
    keyboard: false,
    dragging: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    boxZoom: false,
    doubleClickZoom: false,
    scrollWheelZoom: false,
    tap: false,
    touchZoom: false,
    center: [51.505, -0.09],
    zoom: 13,
    minZoom: 13,
    maxZoom: 13
});
```